# Como eu declaro um arrray em ionic e utilizo?

Tags: javascript, ionic

```
export class StarterorderPage implements OnInit {
  $orders: [
    { id: number, description: string }
  ];
  constructor( public http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  MyFunction() {
    this.$orders[0].id = 230;
    this.$orders[0].description = 'descricao numero duzentos e trinta ';
    console.log('Observe->', this.$orders[0].id, this.$orders[0].description);
  }
```

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>       at StarterorderPage.push../src/app/starterorder/starterorder.page.ts.StarterorderPage.APIstarterOrder
>   (starterorder.page.ts:24)
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (StarterorderPage.html:24)
>       at handleEvent (core.js:23107)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24177)
>       at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:23904)
>       at dispatchEvent (core.js:20556)
>       at core.js:21003
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (platform-browser.js:993)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:423)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)

Esse codigo nao esta funcionando!!! Como eu consigo declarar e adicionar valores e depois usa-los?

Comment: Seu problema não é com o Ionic nem TS e sim com JS

Comment: Sabe como eu resolvo? Em tese, apenas preciso preencher o array orders de forma correta e depois passar para um chamada de webservice...apenas isso e nao consigo!

Comment: tenta $orders.push({230,'descricao numero duzentos e trinta '});

Comment: Lê aqui como faz pra usar arrays no JS : https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Qual versão do Ionic você esta utilizando? Isso aqui não te [ajuda?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39407753/10514656)

Comment: eu li tudo! Entendi...estou utilizando a versao 4 do ionic. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para adicionar elementos em um array, faça assim:

```
MyFunction() {
    this.$orders.push({id: 230, description: 'descricao numero duzentos e trinta '});
    console.log('Observe->', this.$orders[0].id, this.$orders[0].description);
}
```

Eu gosto sempre de iniciar um array mesmo que vazio. Isso evita muitos problemas:

```
    $orders: { id: number, description: string }[] = [];
```

Comment: **Certinho! Problema resolvido! Muito obrigado pelo capricho e pelo seu tempo! Obrigado a todos!**